# Is there a way to extract who has viewed a particular post from the Twitter-API?

Tags: api, twitter

Is it possible to see who has viewed a particular post(ex: detail expand, link click).  From the docs, it doesn't look like it.  I just wanted to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope (as of Jan, 2019).

But you might be able to find who liked, retweeted, or replied to it by writing queries that use fields like `in_reply_to_status_id` (whether that's possible will depend on what endpoint you're using to retrieve data).

Comment: (I'm less certain about the case where it's your own tweet you want to inspect views of -- though as you note, if that were possible, they'd probably document it)